# How to ensure read() to read data from the real device each time?

Tags: linux

I'm periodically reading from a file and checking the readout to decide subsequent action. As this file may be modified by some mechanism which will bypass the block file I/O manipulation layer in the Linux kernel, I need to ensure the read operation reading data from the real underlying device instead of the kernel buffer.

I know fsync() can make sure all I/O write operations completed with all data written to the real device, but it's not for I/O read operations.

The file has to be kept opened.

So could anyone please kindly tell me how I can do to meet such requirement in Linux system? is there such a API similar to fsync() that can be called?

Really appreciate your help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe that you want to use the O_DIRECT flag to `open()`.

Comment: It cost me time to try out the using of O_DIRECT flag. It turns out that macro _GNU_SOURCE has to be defined before corresponding header files included and some restrictions on buffer address alignment has to be taken care. It works perfectly now. posix_padvise also being tried, but seems does not work precisely as I needed. Combination of mmap & madvise not being tried. Thank you all!

Answer (score 1):

I think memory mapping in combination with madvise() and/or posix_fadvise() should satisfy your requirements... Linus contrasts this with O_DIRECT at http://kerneltrap.org/node/7563 ;-).

Comment: It is almost cynical that the same guy (Linus) who mocks O_DIRECT as totally braindamaged opposed to non-O_DIRECT (buffered) kernel AIO in the same manner at another occasion. So, you're stupid if you use it, and you're stupid if you ask why you're forced to use it. :)   But back to topic, you're right insofar as mmap/madvise will incidentially work fine unless someone else uses AIO. However, that is an implementation detail, not guaranteed by POSIX.

Answer (score 0):

You are going to be in trouble if another device is writing to the block device at the same time as the kernel.

The kernel *assumes* that the block device won't be written by any other party than itself. This is true *even if the filesystem is mounted readonly*.

Even if you used direct IO, the kernel may cache filesystem metadata, so a change in the location of those blocks of the file may result in incorrect behaviour.

So in short - don't do that.

If you wanted, you could access the block device directly - which might be a more successful scheme, but still potentially allowing harmful race-conditions (you cannot guarantee the order of the metadata and data updates by the other device). These could cause you to end up reading junk from the device (if the metadata were updated before the data). You'd better have a mechanism of detecting junk reads in this case.

I am of course, assuming some very simple braindead filesystem such as FAT. That might reasonably be implemented in userspace (mtools, for instance, does)